# conditional validation with yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I have 3 fields in a form, the "type" field is select and from that list, some items enable or disable the "out" field, if is enable I need the "out" field to be less than the "in" field and vice-versa, but if the "out" field is disabled I don't need that validation, I was trying something with .when, but is not working, any ideas on how to do this?

```
  const [disableOutCounterField, setDisableOutCounterField] = useState(false);

  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    type: yup.string().required(requiredMessage),
    in: yup
      .number(numberMessage)
      .required(requiredMessage)
      .integer(integerMessage)
      .min(1, positiveMessage)
      .typeError(numberMessage)
      .when("out", {
        is: !disableOutCounterField,
        then: yup.number().moreThan(yup.ref("out"), moreThanMessage),
        message: moreThanMessage,
      }),
    out: yup
      .number(numberMessage)
      .integer(integerMessage)
      .typeError(numberMessage)
      .lessThan(yup.ref("in"), lessThanMessage),
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construct:

```
.when("out", {
  is: !disableOutCounterField,
```

compares the `out` value with `!disableOutCounterField`, and if they are equal, the `then` rule is applied. But quite likely they are never the same.

The check that is needed here is just the value of `!disableOutCounterField` by itself, for any value of `out`. This can be done using an expression:

```
.when("out", {
  is: value => !disableOutCounterField,
```

In words: for every `out` value, return `!disableOutCounterField`, and if it returns true, apply the `then` part.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative I found for this is to regenerate the object `validationSchema` from inside a `useEffect`.

This has the benefit of using `useState` without having them mapped to specific form fields ahead of time, such as if you set something conditionally from the database and don't want to set it as a hidden field somewhere.

```
const validationPiece = yup.object({
amount: yup
  .number()
  .typeError('Please enter an amount')
  .required('Please enter an amount')
});

const [validationSchema, setValidaitonSchema] = useState(yup.object({}));

const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  reset,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm({
  resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (needNewPartOfForm) {
    const validationSchemaDict = {};
    if (needNewPartOfForm.xyz) {
      validationSchemaDict['xyz'] = validationPiece; // does this need a cloneDeep?
    }
    if (needNewPartOfForm.abc) {
      validationSchemaDict['abc'] = validationPiece;
    }
    setValidaitonSchema(yup.object(validationSchemaDict));
  }
}, [clientDocs, clientId, reset, teamId]);
```